# Mouse events handlers

Tags: objective-c, delegates, target-action

MyNSImageView is a subclass of NSImageView, here I have:

```
@interface MyNSImageView : NSImageView 
{
}
@end

@implementation MyNSImageView

//- (void) mouseDown: (NSEvent *) theEvent 
//{
//  do not wish to implement mouseDown event handler from here
//}
@end
```

In another class called MainView, I have:

```
@interface MainView : NSView 
{
    MyNSImageView *ImageView1;
    MyNSImageView *ImageView2;

}
@end

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    ImageView1 = [[[MyNSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(5, 5, 240, 240)] autorelease];
    NSImage* image1 = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"/Volumes/MAC DAT2/pictures/MP6107.jpg"] autorelease];
    [ImageView1 setImage:image1];
    [self addSubview:ImageView1];

    ImageView2 = [[[MyNSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(300, 5, 240, 240)] autorelease];
    image1 = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"/Volumes/MAC DAT2/pictures/MP5784.jpg"] autorelease];
    [ImageView2 setImage:image1];
    [self addSubview:ImageView2];
}

- (void) mouseDown2: (NSEvent *) theEvent 
{
    NSLog(@"mousedown2 from MainView");
}
- (void) mouseDown1: (NSEvent *) theEvent 
{
    NSLog(@"mousedown1 from MainView");
}
@end

- (void) mouseDown: (NSEvent *) theEvent 
{
    NSLog(@"mousedown from MainView");
}
```

In the MainView, when I click on the ImageView1 or ImageView2, I would like to have the mouseDown1 or mouseDown2 method to handle the event accordingly not the mouseDown method.

I have read about target/action/delegate and responder stuff, but still could not see the exact syntax to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this is with a delegate:

First you declare a delegate protocol for your `NSImageView` subclass:

```
@class MyNSImageView;
@protocol MyNSImageViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)myImageView:(MyNSImageView *)view mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;

@end


@interface MyNSImageView : NSImageView {

}
// declare the delegate member
@property (assign) id<MyNSImageViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation MyNSImageView
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

// In your mouseDown method, notify the delegate
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myImageView:mouseDown:)]) {
        [self.delegate myImageView:self mouseDown:event];
    }
}

@end
```

Then, declare your `MainView` class to implement the MyNSImageViewDelegate protocol:

```
@interface MainView : NSView <MyNSImageViewDelegate> {
    MyNSImageView *imageView1;
    MyNSImageView *imageView2;
}
@end
```

And in your `MainView` implementation:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // create your image views then add our instance as the delegate to each
    ImageView1.delegate = self;
    ImageView2.delegate = self;
}

// here we implement the `MyNSImageViewDelegate` method, which will get 
// called when any `MyImageNSView` instance we've added ourselves as
// delegate to gets clicked.
- (void)myImageView:(MyNSImageView *)view mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (view == imageView1) {
        NSLog(@"imageView1 clicked");    
    } else if (view == imageView2) {
        NSLog(@"imageView2 clicked");    
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it.  I knew it will involved selector and delegate stuff.  But could not make all the connection together.  Good job!!!  If you are familiar with C# or C++, they handled this situation much simpler.
(btw: one line missing in your code is "@synthesize delegate;".  It will need to be in the implementation file of MyNSImageView.)

Just a side question:  Will my implementation of the mouse events handling in this manner conform to the MVC model?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing @synthesize... sorry about that.

Comment: Check my edit for another valid approach... the target-action mechanism is probably the most idiomatic Cocoa/MVC approach here.

Comment: setAction for NSImageView does not mean the same as mouse click (as for the Button, etc.)  So, setAction would not work what I was trying to accomplish (different mouse events: right mouse, left mouse button, etc.)  I think your original solution was a right approach and technically sounded.

Comment: The action of an `NSImageView` is sent when the user drops an image onto the image view, not when it’s clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [the responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html). For MyCallingClass's -mouseDown: method to be called, an instance of that class has to be in the current responder chain, and no other responder further down the chain should handle that event.

Comment: Caleb: Thanks for your response.  My original question was not clear.  I made some change to the question.  If the mouseDown event handler was not implemented in the MyNSImageView then the mouseDown event handler from the MainView (MyCallingClass) will take over.  But I need to be able to distinguished the mousedown event from different images.  Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.