# When to use a colon with a @selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, selector, nsnotifications

Just getting going with iPhone development and `Objective-C`.

Yesterday I was trying to addObserver for a notification in a view of mine, and I kept getting this error:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I tracked it down to the fact that I needed to include the trailing colon to my selector argument:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nameOfMySelector:) name:@"BBLocationServicesAreDisabled" object:nil];
```

Today, I thought I was clever because when setting up the action argument to a button, I remembered my mistake yesterday, and added the colon to the action argument.  The action argument takes a `@selector`, just like the selector argument while setting up an observer for an `NSNotification`, so I figured I was doing the right thing.

However, with the following code:

```
[self.callToActionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nameOfMySelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I get the exact same error:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What gives?  Why does one `@selector` require a trailing colon, and the other doesn't?  What are the rules I should follow for when it should be included and when it should be left off, and why I can't I always just do one or the other?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a colon, not a semicolon. Anyway, what is the prototype of your `nameOfMySelector:` method? What kind of argument does it want?

Comment: Also are you referring to the same method in both cases?

Comment: Ha!  An oversight on my part; I've edited the post to refer to them as colon's.

Comment: and I have corrected the title.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As mentioned by boltClock, the character you are referring to is actually a colon.  The difference between `@selector(method)` and `@selector(method:)` is the method signature.  The 2nd variant expects a parameter to be passed.

`@selector(method)` would expect the method:  `-(void)method`

`@selector(method:)` would expect the method:  `-(void)method:(id)someParameter`

Comment: There we go, that's exactly it.  Makes total sense.  Thanks for the quick answer and for the grammar lesson :)

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be missing one concept here: colon is, in some way, a part of the method name. E.g., method

```
-(IBAction) doIt:(id)sender;
```

has name `doIt:`. Thus, colon should be used to reference this method.
But this method doesn't have a colon at the end

```
-(IBAction) doItWithoutParameter;
```

Same goes for methods accepting multiple arguments, they have names like `doItWithParam1:andParam2:`

Answer (score 7):

A selector represents a method name, and the number of colons in a selector matches the number of arguments in the corresponding method:

1. `mySelector` — no colon, no arguments, e.g. `- (void)mySelector;`, `[self mySelector];`
2. `mySelectorWithFoo:` — one colon, a single argument, e.g. `- (void)mySelectorWithFoo:(Foo *)foo;`, `[self mySelectorWithFoo:someFoo];`
3. `mySelectorWithFoo:withBar:` — two colons, two arguments, e.g. `- (void)mySelectorWithFoo:(Foo *)foo bar:(Bar *)bar;`, `[self mySelectorWithFoo:someFoo bar:someBar];`

and so forth.

It is also possible to have a selector without ‘naming’ the parameters. It’s not recommended since it’s not immediately clear what the parameters are:

1. `mySelector::` — two colons, two arguments, e.g. `- (void)mySelector:(Foo *)foo :(Bar *)bar;`, `[self mySelector:someFoo :someBar];`
2. `mySelector:::` — three colons, three arguments, e.g. `- (void)mySelector:(int)x :(int)y :(int)z;`, `[self mySelector:2 :3 :5];`

Answer (score 2):

The colon indicates that the method takes a parameter.

`[someObject performSelector:@selector(doSomething:)]` means that doSomething is expecting a parameter.

`[someObject performSelector:@selector(doSomething)]` means that doSomething doesn't need any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In your case:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nameOfMySelector:) name:@"BBLocationServicesAreDisabled" object:nil];

- (void) nameOfMySelector: (NSNotification *) notification {
    /* this method would require the semi-colon */
}
```

or in this case:

```
[self.callToActionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nameOfMySelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void) nameOfMySelector: (id) sender {
    /* this method would also require the semi-colon */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the missing parameter.

See this post: [Objective-C: Calling selectors with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments/1019061#1019061) (Great answers!)