# How do you add an action to a button programmatically in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, programmatically-created

I know how to add an IBAction to a button by dragging from the interface builder, but I want to add the action programmatically to save time and to avoid switching back and forth constantly. The solution is probably really simple, but I just can't seem to find any answers when I search it. Thank you!

Answer (score 227):

Try this:

**Swift 4**

```swift
myButton.addTarget(self,
                   action: #selector(myAction),
                   for: .touchUpInside)
```

**Objective-C**

```c
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(myAction) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You can find a rich source of information in Apple's Documentation. Have a look at the [UIButton's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton), it will reveal that UIButton is a descendant of [UIControl,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) which implements the method to [add targets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget).

--

You'll need to pay attention to whether add colon or not after `myAction` in
`action:@selector(myAction)`

Here's the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953651/763459).

Comment: What if I want to pass a parameter to the selector when my button is pressed (eg. I have a button inside a UITableViewCell and I want to pass the object in that cell when the cell's button is pressed)?

Comment: @acecapades I think you are mixing two things. You can't attach a paramater like you could do with performSelector. The action pattern used by the UIControl descendant UIButton is to notifiy some target with a certain selector when controlEvent is triggered. When this happens in your case you could go up the superviews to see who is encapsulating your button and ask a method to resolve the tablecell to model relation and then do whatever you want with that.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I think I understand what you're saying. Thanks for the tip Nick!

Comment: can someone translate this in swift?

Answer (score 25):

Swift answer:

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "click:", for: .touchUpInside)

func click(sender: UIButton) {
    print("click")
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget

Comment: What's the ":" for after "click" in the call to UIControl.addTarget?

Comment: Selectors have a `:` as placeholders for function arguments. Since `click` takes the `sender` argument, that is replaced with a `:` in the selector string.

Comment: This worked recently for me for Swift 3.   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.click), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)   func click() {
    print("click")
} Thanks @Glauco Neves for pointing us down the right track

Answer (score 14):

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 10, 80, 100, 30 );
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
        [button setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitleColor: [UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: is it possible to add 2 or more actions?

Answer (score 9):

try this:

first write this in your .h file of viewcontroller

```
UIButton *btn;
```

Now write this in your .m file of viewcontrollers viewDidLoad.

```
btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, 30, 30)];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
//adding action programatically
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

write this outside viewDidLoad method in .m file of your view controller

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
   //Write a code you want to execute on buttons click event
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( x-pos, y-pos, width, height );   //
 CGRectMake(10,5,10,10) 

 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];

 button setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [button setTitleColor: [UIColor BlueVolor] forState:
 UIControlStateNormal];

 [view addSubview:button];




 -(void)btnClicked {
    // your code }
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 3**

Create a function for button action first and then add the function to your button target

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
}

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction),for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIButton *btnNotification=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnNotification.frame=CGRectMake(130,80,120,40);
btnNotification.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
[btnNotification setTitle:@"create Notification" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnNotification addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnNotification];


}

-(void)btnClicked
{
    // Here You can write functionality 

}
```

Comment: please provide some comments explaining how your sample can help.

Comment: UIButton *btnNotification=[UIButton        buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnNotification.frame=CGRectMake(130,80,120,40);//Button Frame Setting
    btnNotification.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    [btnNotification setTitle:@"create Notification"      forState:UIControlStateNormal];//Set the title for button
    [btnNotification addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//add Target For button
    [self.view addSubview:btnNotification];} -(void)btnClicked { // Here You can write functionality

}

Comment: -(void)btnClicked                                     
 {
 
 //here what ever you want you can set the action for button 
 //Example:go to next viewcontroller
 
 nextviewController *nextPage=[nextviewController alloc]init];
 [self.navigationController pushviewcontroller:nextPage animated:YES ];
 
 }

Answer (score 2):

`UIButton` inherits from `UIControl`. That has all of the methods to add/remove actions: [UIControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl). Look at the section "Preparing and Sending Action Messages", which covers `– sendAction:to:forEvent:` and `– addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(aMethod1:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1):

IOS 14 SDK:
you can add action with closure callback:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system, primaryAction: UIAction(title: "Button Title", handler: { _ in
            print("Button tapped!")
        }))
```

Getting a reference to the control sender

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.addAction(UIAction(title: "", handler: { action in
    let textField = action.sender as! UITextField
    print("Text is \(textField.text)")
}), for: .editingChanged)
```

[source](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/uibutton-uicontrol-closure-target/?utm_source=SwiftLee%20-%20Subscribers&utm_campaign=5ddd08c724-EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_2020_03_02_08_48_COPY_01&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e154f6bfee-5ddd08c724-398554018)