# How to add action for UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am new to iPhone technology. Please anyone tell me how to add action for UIButton.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25);
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.center = self.center;
[self addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Not about the question but you have a memory leak here. don't call retain on the button if you don't call release on it later. The retain is not needed as the button is not an ivar and is autoreleased.

Comment: Removed the memory leak.

Comment: [IOS 14 SDK: you can add action with closure callback:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843427/how-do-you-add-an-action-to-a-button-programmatically-in-xcode/640871599#answer-64087159)

Answer (score 11):

Use This

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 7):

You specify selectors using *@selector()*. So, the *action* parameter looks like,

```
action:@selector(buttonClick:)
```

Answer (score 3):

**iOS 14.0+**

you can use UIAction instead of addTarget:

```
            // Example: action to remove or add in the favorite list of recipes
    button.addAction(
        UIAction { _ in
            if self.isFavorite {
                self.isFavorite = false
                print("✅: Recipe is not favorite")
            } else {
                self.isFavorite = true
                print("✅ Recipe is favorite")
            }
        }, for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Like This

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25);
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.center = self.center;
[self addSubview:btn];
```

and add your selector method

```
-(IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
action:@selector(buttonClick:)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift code:

```
button.addTarget(self, action:"action_button", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
...
func action_button() {
    //  implement me
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function with `@objc`
2. add the function as a target to the `UIButton`.  like so:

```swift
menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```