# IOS: action for button pressed

Tags: ios, button

In my app I want to do an action when button is pressed and when I release this button I want that this action stop its execution. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add targets to your button for both control states, `UIControlEventTouchDown` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`

Comment: How does this help perform an action when the button is pressed (but not yet released)?

Answer (score -2):

Besides the fact that this is such a basic task that has been ask 1000 times, read a bit of this [Apple's documentation on target action!](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html)

EDIT: I don't see why you would downvote. I provided a link where he can find the answer himself, and it's not like that the answer is super easy to find with google in 5 minutes. He didn't provide anything on his own effort.

This is not:"please post code on how to solve this"...

Comment: I don't know what the down votes are about, and this question definitely has been asked before. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341543/how-to-add-action-for-uibutton