# UIButton action not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uibutton

I am having some trouble with the UIButton.

This is my code:

[image]

I am not using the Interface Builder and I am a new programmer.

What I want is that when the button is selected the title changes and the button's transparency changes from half visible to fully visible.

Thanks in advance, -Marnix

Comment: Where is that code? What exactly isn't working, and how do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: 1. It's the .m file. 2. It show the first 'if' statement effect, not the @"UnTapped" one.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want the button to be half transparent when selected (alpha: 0.5), and fully visible when not selected

Comment: This code is inside the `IBAction` of the button?

Comment: As I stated before; I do no use the Interface Builder, so I do not need IBAction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843427/how-do-you-add-an-action-to-a-button-programmatically-in-xcode

Comment: @Marnix, without `IBAction`, you'll never reach your goal. no matter, you are in the _Interface Builder_ or you create the `UIButton` dynamically, the button's behaviour is still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `if` statement is just executed once, when you're creating the button. Inside `MyCode2`, add this line:

```
[Button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Every time that the button's pressed, the `buttonAction` method will be executed, so:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    if(Button1.selected == NO) {
        // Do your "NO" stuff
    }else if(Button1.selected == YES) {
        // Do your "YES" stuff
    }
}
```

You have to declare this IBAction in your `.h` and add this method in your `.m` file.

Comment: Actually, you may not need to declare it in `.h`, since it will not be used by other classed anyway.

Comment: That's true, @Selkie. I'm that kind of developer that likes everything really organized... :-P

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should set title for different control state like

```
[Button1 setTitle:@"UnTapped" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Second, you don't need to put `setTitle` method inside of this check.

Besides, you need to put this check inside of a method of the button to make it work. If you didn't use IB, then just use `addTarget: action: forControlEvent` like

```
[Button1 addTarget:self actoin:@selector(changeButtonState:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Lastly, did you make the button keep selected after touch? If not, add

```
Button1.selected = !Button1.selected
```

in the method. All in all, your method should looks like this

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    Button1.selected = !Button1.selected
    if(Button1.selected == NO) {
        Button1.alpha = 0.5
    }else if(Button1.selected == YES) {
        Button1.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also put your answer as 'the answer' if I could set multiple answers. Thanks anyway.