# Programmatically code UIButton action

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I'm trying to create a button, which once tapped will show a popover of another UIView. To test this out, I have the following code in my viewDidLoad section:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.hard1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.hard1 setFrame:CGRectMake(884, 524, 105, 60)]; // set the x,y,width and height based on your specs
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.jpg"];
    hard1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    hard1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [hard1 addTarget: self
              action: @selector(buttonClicked:)
    forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.hard1 setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:self.hard1];
}
```

and further down:

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked: (id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Tap");
}
```

however, the console does not log 'Tap' when I hit the button. Any ideas?

Comment: [IOS 14 SDK: you can add action with closure callback:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843427/how-do-you-add-an-action-to-a-button-programmatically-in-xcode/640871599#answer-64087159)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Watch these three lines of code:

```
hard1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
hard1.clipsToBounds = YES;
[hard1 addTarget: self
          action: @selector(buttonClicked:)
forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You are missing self. in all three. They should be:

```
self.hard1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.hard1.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.hard1 addTarget: self
          action: @selector(buttonClicked:)
forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Also, if you are creating it programatically, it shouldn't be an IBAction (IB stands for interface builder and this is not created in interface builder).

Comment: Now that I'm on it. When you create a property do this in synthesize: @synthesize hard1 = _hard1; This way referring to the property as just "hard1" wont work. It's either self.hard1 or _hard1 (the latter only to be used in the setter method)

Answer (score 4):

```
    self.hard1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


 [hard1 addTarget: self
              action: @selector(buttonClicked:)    forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Replace hard1 to self.hard1

Answer (score 0):

You have put the event responder as `buttonClicked` but in `IBAction` you have defined `buttonTap`. This would obviously not work...

It should be

```
[hard1 addTarget: self
              action: @selector(buttonTap:)
    forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I made a typo. My actual code is edited above, still doesn't work.