# How to put this Objective-C code in the button action?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
ActionsViewController *actionsViewController = [AppLibrary createActionsViewController];
actionsViewController.actionDelegate = self;
actionsViewController.supportedActionTypes = @[[[SupportedAction alloc] initWithActionType:ActionTypeEdit mediaTypes:@[kTypePNG]]];

[actionsViewController setWhitelistedSubTypes:@[@"adjust", @"filter", @"healing"]];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.actionsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:actionsViewController];
    [self presentViewController:self.actionsNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: - (IBAction)go:(id)sender ;

Comment: just how to call this code from button ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843427/how-do-you-add-an-action-to-a-button-programmatically-in-xcode. In the button event, you can paste your required code for functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this in

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
ActionsViewController *actionsViewController = [AppLibrary createActionsViewController];
actionsViewController.actionDelegate = self;
actionsViewController.supportedActionTypes = @[[[SupportedAction alloc] initWithActionType:ActionTypeEdit mediaTypes:@[kTypePNG]]];

[actionsViewController setWhitelistedSubTypes:@[@"adjust", @"filter", @"healing"]];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.actionsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:actionsViewController];
    [self presentViewController:self.actionsNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

Please check the following Doc:
[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingAction.html)