# iPhone: Difference in @selector syntax

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Most likely a dumb question, but what's the difference between:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Join" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:self action:@selector(pressJoinButton)];
```

and

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Join" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:self action:@selector(pressJoinButton:)];
```

Notice how one is pressJoinButton, and the other is pressJoinButton:

Comment: Possibly addressed in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953623/when-to-use-a-colon-with-a-selector

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use a colon with a @selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953623/when-to-use-a-colon-with-a-selector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colon is used to add arguments to the method you are calling, so if pressJoinButton had zero arguments, it would be:

```
pressJoinButton
```

If it had one argument, it would be:

```
pressJoinButton:
```

if it had 2 arguments, it would be:

```
pressJoinButton:withArg1:
```

if it had 3 arguments it would be:

```
pressJoinButton:withArg1:withArg2:
```

etc

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

The main (and only) difference is that `pressJoinButton` and `pressJoinButton:` are to totally distinct and unrelated selectors. This is mainly because the colons are part of a method's name in ObjectiveC.

The difference between `pressJoinButton` and `pressJoinButton:` is about the same as the difference between `void pressJoinButton();` and `void pressJoinButton(id sender);` when declared in a language with support for function overloading. They are two totally different methods/functions.

`pressJoinButton` would refer to a method of a pattern like this:

```
- (void)pressJoinButton;
```

while `pressJoinButton:` would refer to a method of a pattern like this:

```
- (IBAction)pressJoinButton:(id)sender;
```

---

This also applies for methods with multiple arguments:

```
- (void)doFoo:(Foo *)foo withBar:(Bar *)bar inFoobar:(Foobar *)foobar;
```

which translates to the following selector:

```
doFoo:withBar:inFoobar:
```

and which in function-like syntaxt you would probably have declared like this:

```
void doFooWithBarInFoobar(Foo *foo, Bar *bar, Foobar *foobar);
```

Answer (score 1):

For first sample action declaration is:

`- (void)pressJoinButton;`

For second:

`- (void)pressJoinButton:(id)sender;`