# UIButton addSelector multiple parameters

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` as follows :

```
[btnMailAddress addTarget:self action:@selector(showMap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

My question is, how can I send multiple parameters in **showMap** method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just googling [selector multiple parameters](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=@selector%20parameters&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=selector%20multiple%20parameters&pbx=1&oq=selector%20multiple%20parameters&aq=f&aqi=g-v2g-m2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=80263l83127l0l83597l10l10l0l0l0l7l550l4301l3-3.5.2l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ab4e276edd9a6586&biw=1440&bih=799) gives many relevant answers.

1st result - [Calling selectors with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you need to call a method with multiple parameters, you'll need to first redirect it through an "IBAction"-type method (i.e., -(void)action:(id)sender ).