# Passing arguments to selector in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

My function looks like this

```
-(void) doTransition:(id)sender withID:(int) n
```

How do I pass int n to selector,

```
target:self selector:@selector(doTransition:)withID:3
```

this won't work

Please help
Thanks

Comment: you can send NSDictionary instance with all attributes that you need :) Then your function will look like `-doTransition:(NSDictionary*)info`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't. methods like performSelector: are set up to pass NSObjects as parameters, not scalar values.

There is a method performSelector:withObject:withObject: that will invoke a method with 2 object parameters.

You can trigger a method with any type of parameters by creating an NSInvocation, but it's a fair amount of work, and a little tricky to figure out how to do it.

In your case it would be simpler to refactor your method to take the ID parameter as an NSNumber object.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be an object

Answer (score 6):

So, I Googled "calling selectors with arguments" and got a bunch of results, the first of which is a question here on SO: [Objective-C: Calling selectors with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments)

The most voted answer there has some details, specifically:

```
[selectorTarget performSelector:mySelector withObject:@3];
```

This is a simple task to perform. More information can be found at the linked question/answer area.

Notice the `@3` I passed, which is not an  `int` but an `NSNumber`. If you have an `int` value  you can easily get an `NSNumber` by performing `[NSNumber numberWithInt:myIntValue]`. The `@3` is shorthand syntax available in clang 3.4 for creating an `NSNumber` with an integer value. The use of `NSNumber` here instead of `int` is important because this selector call expects an `id` type as the `withObject:` parameter and so thus I need an object, and not a primitive type (whether the compiler auto-wraps for you, I can't say).

Another important note is that there are three `performSelector:` functions defined:

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject;
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject withObject:(id)anotherObject;
```

So you can see you can use functions that don't take values and functions that take one or two values as selectors but outside of that you'd most likely need to write your own logic for calling functions with greater than 2 arity.

Comment: Instead of "write your own logic for calling functions" you can also use NSInvocation to call a selector with more than 2 parameters or for a selector which returns something.

Comment: @Geraud.ch Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't that qualify as "writing your own logic?" This means that you use whatever tools you have that allow you to do so, but it's not something that is available for you attached to an Object like the `performSelector:` functions.

Comment: I thought you would like to say: wrap your method with arguments in another method so that you can use the same performSelector. The goal was to add a pointer to NSInvocation, not to disagree with you :)

Comment: @Geraud.ch Ah, I gotcha. To be honest, I'm not really familiar enough with `NSInvocation` to offer that out as advice, and I only refrain from mentioning it because it's been mentioned in comments and another answer as well. Although it is a good point of research.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful

Comment: @izuriel, it looks like you and I posted pretty much the same answer within a short time of each other. I suspect you posted yours while I was composing mine.

Comment: @DuncanC It happens a lot, I did up vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It not easy to use NSNumber to pass value, I implemented a method to pass an object as int.

```
+ (void)showNotice:(NSString *)str atView:(UIView *)view delay:(int)delay {
    [cc_message cc_instance:CC_Notice.shared method:@selector(showNotice:atView:delay:) params:str,view,Int(delay)];
}
```

And use invocation to receive and reduction to int.

```
CC_Int *ccint = (CC_Int *)obj;
int value = ccint.value;
[invocation setArgument:&value atIndex:i+2];
```

Comment: this also resolved performSelector: can only pass 2 (as max) objects. It can pass object as many as you want.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass a NSDictionary with the values you want to send, something like:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"myInt"];
```

Comment: I don't see how wrapping the value inside of a dictionary solves the question in "How do I pass this value to a selector?" where there is no code demonstrating that the person is aware of the functions needed to pass objects.