# Tuple as function parameter gives "Unrecognized selector sent..."

Tags: swift, tuples, selector

I have a function declared like this:

```
func rspGetCategories(_ response: (Int, [String:Any])) {
```

I try to call it like this:

```
self.perform(act, with: (tag, outjson))
```

Where:

```
act = Selector(("rspGetCategories:"))
tag = 1
outjson = ["status":"ServerError"]
```

I just get an "unrecognized selector sent...". What am I missing here?

Full error message:

```
    2018-07-18 11:20:15.852755+0200 Appname[8071:4529543] -[Appname.ViewController rspGetCategories:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10380be00
2018-07-18 11:20:15.853361+0200 Appname[8071:4529543] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Appname.ViewController rspGetCategories:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10380be00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18418ed8c 0x1833485ec 0x18419c098 0x18e27edb0 0x1841945c8 0x18407a41c 0x1020f5dfc 0x1020ebc3c 0x102f811dc 0x102f8119c 0x102f85d2c 0x184137070 0x184134bc8 0x184054da8 0x186039020 0x18e071758 0x1020fec34 0x183ae5fc0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Could you show the full error message?

Comment: Updated the question with full error message.

Comment: Which version of Swift do you use? What about using `#selector(rspGetCategories(_:))` instead? Also you might need `@objc` before `func rspGetCategories(_ response: (Int, [String:Any])) {`?

Comment: I use Swift 4. If I use #selector, i have to use @objc on the function, and then I get an error saying that Objective-C can't handle tuples.

Comment: If you use #selector then you must use @objc, I don't see how you can get around that rule other than refactoring or not using #selector

Comment: I don't use #selector

Comment: It's the same as Selector() isn't it, and you wrote #selector in your previous comment. Talk about nitpicking

Comment: No, Selector() does not require @objc. That's why I use Selector()

Comment: I have no idea where you got that from, do you have a reference for this claim? I believe Selector is a swift structure used when calling objective-c.

Comment: Also in Swift 4 you get a compiler warning when using Selector() instead of #selector

Comment: This is how it works, but it is besides the question. I need a solution that allows me to pass two values through .perform.

Comment: Do you really need a Tuple? What about using a custom Class, or a Dictionary: `["tag": tag, "json": json]`? Or see there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910588/passing-arguments-to-selector-in-objective-c ?

Comment: I guess that would do the trick. Should we conclude that tuples would be impossible in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `selector` method should be representable by `Objective-C` so with `@objc`, we can not pass tuple as parameter for a method otherwise compiler will throw this error,

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot
>   be represented in Objective-C

**One** possible solution is as below,

```
@objc func rspGetCategories(_ response: [String: Any]) {
    print("Tag: \(response["tag"] as! Int) Status:\(response["status"] as! String)")
}
```

And construct the response as below,

```
let selector = #selector(rspGetCategories(_:))
let tag = 1
let response: [String: Any] = ["tag": tag,
                               "status": "ServerError"]
self.perform(selector, with: response)
```

**Another** solution is to pass two parameters instead of tuple. As below,

```
@objc func rspGetCategories(_ tag: NSNumber, response: [String: Any]) {
    print("\(tag.intValue) \(response)")
}

let selector = #selector(rspGetCategories(_:response:))
let tag = 1
let response = ["status": "ServerError"]
self.perform(selector, with: tag, with: response)
```

Remember that `selector` method `argument` `type` needs to be a `reference type`.

Comment: Something strange is happening, though... I went for the second approach, and it seems the value of tag gets corrupted. When I pass 0 in tag, it is received in rspGetCategories as -5764607523034234877

Comment: @RichardG.Nielsen Yes, just checked that code. Actually method to be called from perform should have reference type parameters to work consistently.

Comment: You will need a little update in method signature as `rspGetCategories(_ tag: NSNumber, response: [String: Any])` and then you can use the `tag.intValue` to get the integer value. I hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: I found the exact same solution, and came here to tell about it, but you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Split your tuple into two parameters like

```
@objc func rspGetCategories(_ response: Int, dict: [String: Any]) {
```

and change the selector

```
let act = #selector(Test.rspGetCategories(_:dict:))
```

`Test` is the name of my class, replace it with your class name