# new to ios - unrecognized selector sent to instance message

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

here is my code:

```
-(void)flash_random_winning_number:(NSInteger)param_which_magic_number
{


NSInteger dd = 9;


NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5
                          target:self
                          selector:@selector(ShowLabel22:dd:)
                           userInfo:Nil
                           repeats: YES
                  ];



}//flash_random_winning_number
```

the problem is with selector:@selector(ShowLabel22:dd:) because I am sending a parameter to this method called ShowLabel22:

```
-(void)ShowLabel:(NSInteger)param_which_magic_number
{
random_magic_number1.hidden = NO;
}
```

however if I were to remove the parameters from all this code, then there is no error. Therefore it seems as if I have mistake in the way I am using parameters.

Comment: Holy inconsistent naming conventions, Batman!   Methods should always begin with a lower case letter.  Method names and parameters should always be camelCased.   That also isn't how you pass arguments to methods;  simply tacking the variable onto the selector won't work.    You should take a step back and focus on learning Objective-C.

Comment: First change name of your selector. And please read UIKit framework,  to which object we can hide or show.

Comment: thanks for the tip on methods bbum

Comment: There is no method named `ShowLabel22:dd:`.

Answer (score 2):

The selector you pass to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` is akin to the name of a function. What you’re trying to do is to pass in the name of a function *and* the value of its parameters, but that won’t work. The method you name using `@selector(...)` will be passed exactly one argument: the `NSTimer` object calling the method.

If you have data you need to make available to `ShowLabel` it needs to be attached to the timer object or to `self` or something like that. To attach your number to the timer object you could do this:

```
- (void) flash_random_winning_number:(NSInteger) param_which_magic_number
{
    NSInteger dd = 9;
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(ShowLabel:)
                                                    userInfo:@(dd)
                                                     repeats:YES];
}

- (void) ShowLabel:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSInteger dd = [[timer userInfo] integerValue];
    /* do stuff with dd */
}
```

(Since you’re new to Objective-C I want to mention the conventions that have arisen about method naming. The usual style, which you should always use, is for methods to be named with `camelCasedNamesLikeThis`. In particular, `flash_random_winning_number` and `ShowLabel` are both likely to confuse other Objective-C developers because they don’t “look like” method names. `ShowLabel22` is also weird because of the numbers, but since you included that in one place in your question but not another I guess that’s just a typo.)

Comment: Methods are not functions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments) SO answer. When you have a selector with arguments you have to use this method:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myTest:) withObject:myString];
```

Comment: ok i tried it but it did not work, i modified this line of code: selector:@selector(ShowLabel22:) withObject:dd

Comment: Selector should be called like method name.