# Xcode 6 - UIKeyboardDidShowNotification unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to scroll the view (to prevent the keyboard from hiding text fields), but I can't seem to get the keyboard notification to function properly.

This code is based on Apple's documentation (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)).

First, we add the listener in the `viewDidLoad()` of a `UIViewController` subclass.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWasShown"), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

When the event fires, it crashes immediately with the `unrecognized selector` error message, and won't even print to the console:

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("Keyboard will be SHOWN")
}
```

But without the parameter, I get "Keyboard will be SHOWN" in the console.

```
func keyboardWasShown() {
    println("Keyboard will be SHOWN")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the selector you're using doesn't specify that the method it should notify has a parameter.

Try this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWasShown:"), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

(Note the `:` in the selector.)

See [Objective-C: Calling selectors with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments/1019061) (this still applies in Swift).