# iOS 9 Undeclared selector

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, performselector

Why after updating to iOS 9 does this line of code not work?

The warning is **Undeclared selector 'performThisMethod:_ImageData**

The app crashes on the [self performSelector:]

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performThisMethod:_ImageData:)withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05f];

-(void) performThisMethod : (NSData *) data {
     NSLog(@"Testing this Method");

  }
```

What has Apple changed?

Comment: Apple did not change anything, that code probably was never compilable

Answer (score 1):

You are using `performSelector` incorrectly. You want:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performThisMethod:) withObject:_ImageData afterDelay:0.05f];
```

Better yet, use `dispatch_after`:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.05 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performThisMethod:_ImageData];
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept an answer that solved your issue. This indicates the question is complete and it increases your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably be

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performThisMethod:) withObject:_ImageData afterDelay:0.05f];
```

Take a look at [this question  answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments) to better understand the `performSelector` behaviour.