# How to call a selector

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing the `scheduleTimer` function of a `Timer` in a mock Timer to be able to unit test my code. It looks like this:

```
static func scheduledTimer(
    timeInterval ti: TimeInterval,
    target aTarget: Any,
    selector aSelector: Selector,
    userInfo: Any?,
    repeats yesOrNo: Bool) -> Timer
```

I need to be able to call `aSelector` like a closure, but I'm not sure how that's possible with it being a `Selector`. How can I do this?

Comment: It’s an Objective C mechanism and it’s easy to do in Objective C.

Comment: @matt any way to do it in swift?

Comment: If `aTarget` is not subclass `NSObject` you can't do nothing about it, otherwise you can cast it to `NSObject` and `performSelector…` as usual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Calling selectors with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018195/objective-c-calling-selectors-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: By the way, it does not make much sense to mock timer. You can just call the method directly with the same result.

Comment: You can't.

[reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective-c_runtime_features_in_swift)

As this reference said, Selector refers Object-C method's names.

But I couldn't get a thing. Why you need to use closure instead of creating a method in your test class and send this method to your selector?