# How to pass a parameter by a @selector function in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

```
- (IBAction)alertShow:(NSButton *)sender {
    
    MHAlert* alert = [[MHAlert alloc]initWithMessageTitle:@"message" infoText:@"infoText" btnTitle:@"OK" target:self action:@selector(test:) secondBtnTitle:nil target:nil action:nil];
    [alert runModal];
}

- (void)test:(void(^)(BOOL isSuccess))handler
{
    if (handler) {
        handler(YES);
    }
    else
    {
        handler(NO);
    }
    
}
```

**I want to pass a parameter by @selector(test:), and that is a block type parameter**,
I check the handler in **test:** method, and find it was **not nil**, when I do as code show.
if not, how can I pass a nil value to **test:** method.

I don't want to use **perform:** method, or wrap a mew method after searching on net.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018838/4525734

Comment: What is `MHAlert`?  Does it invoke the supplied selector with an argument?  You can't pass an argument in the `initWithMessageTitle` call; that isn't how `@selector` works.

Comment: You can use `NSInvocation`. Fill it and call `invoke`

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use `perform:withObject:`?

Comment: You can cast the block parameter to an ```id``` and pass that exactly as in the example @hacker_1989 showed.

Comment: Thx for your comment, and that is my wanted. @Cy-4AH

Answer (score 2):

Use NSInvocation inited with parameter in the initWithMessageTitle implementation, and invoke.

```
- (instancetype)initWithMessageTitle:(NSString *)message infoText:(NSString *)info btnTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action secondBtnTitle:(NSString *)secondTitle target:(id)secondTarget action:(SEL)secondAction
{
     NSMethodSignature *sig = [[target class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:action];
     NSInvocation* invoc = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
     //[invoc setArgument: atIndex:2];
     invoc.selector = action;
     [invoc invokeWithTarget:target];
}
```

Fill it and call invoke inspired by Cy-4AH.